# c#: string format

Tags: c#, string

I came across a code. Can anybody shed a bit of light on it. Plz be kind if anybody finds it a bit basic.

```
string str= String.Format("{0,2:X2}", (int)value);
```

Thankyou for your time.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: @SonerGönül Actually, I think this title is very good... all 5 of the first 5 applicable rules have been followed! ;-)  What's the problem you see with it?

Comment: This site is a great help about [string formatting](http://alexonasp.net/samples/stringformatting/).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`X` format returns [Hexadecimal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString) representation of your `value`.

for example `String.Format("{0:X}", 10)` will return `"A"`, not `"10"`

`X2` will add **zeros** to the left, if your hexadecimal representation is less than two symbols

for example `String.Format("{0:X2}", 10)` will return `"0A"`, not `"A"`

`0,2` will add **spaces** to the left, if the resulting number of symbols is less than 2.

for example `String.Format("{0,3:X2}", 10)` will return `"  0A"`, but not `"0A"`

So as result this format `{0,2:X2}` will return your value in Hexadecimal notation appended by one zero from the left if it is only one symbol and then appended by space from the left if is it one symbol. After reading this several times, you can see, that `,2` is redundant and this format can be simplified to `{0:X2}` without changing the behavior.

Some notes:

`:` separates indexing number and specific format **applied to that object**. For example this code

```
String.Format("{0:X} {1:N} {0:N}", 10, 20)
```

shows, that I want to format `10` (index 0) in hexadecimal then show `20` (index 1) in numerical way, and then also format `10` (index 0) in numeric way.

`0,2` from the left part of semi-column indicated index position `0` and format `,2` applied to the **resulting string**, not to a specific object. So this code

```
String.Format("{0,1} {1,2} {0,4}", 10, 20)
```

will print first number with at least one symbol, second with at least two symbols and then again first number with at least four symbols occupied. If the number of symbols in resulting string will be less - they will be populated by spaces.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Two things.1.What is the function of 0 here `String.Format("{0:X}", 10); ` 2. Using `X` is equivalent to using `X1` ?

Answer (score 6):

```
{0,2:X2}
```

It splits into

1. `0,2` - Format a number `10` into `10`
2. `X2` - Formats a number `10` into hexadecimel value `0A`.

### Update

**Code**

```
String.Format("{0,2:X2}", (int)value); // where value = 10
```

**Result:** `0A`

Live Example: http://ideone.com/NW0U26

**Conclusion from me**
You can change `"{0,2:X2}"` to `"{0:X2}"`, [live example here](http://ideone.com/rN3rCE).

Reference Links: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx)

Comment: Nope, the 2 in 0,2 is the left alignment not the decimal digits

Comment: @Steve I do not have Full edition of VS with me ATM but the online compiler supports my result prediction. Can you pls verify if I am wrong or not by simple console app..

Comment: Please try just {0,2}. Do you see decimals?

Answer (score 2):

[According to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx), a format string has the following format:

```
{index[,alignment][:formatString]}
```

We can find all of these components (the last two being optional) in your format string:

**`0`** is the **index** of the parameter to use.
**`,2`** is the **alignment** part, if the result is shorter than that, it is padded left with spaces.
**`:X2`** is the **formatString** part. It means the number will be formatted in hexadecimal (uppercase) format, with a minimum width of 2. If the resulting number has less than 2 digits, it is padded with zeroes on the left.

In this specific case the alignment specifier is redundant, because `X2` already specifies a minimum width of 2.

See here for more info on the format string:
[Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx)
[Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx)